# how to remove "transform" on edit screen imglykit iOS

Tags: ios, imglykit

using [imglyKit](https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-ios) library for iOS, how can i remove the "Transform", crop tool from the image editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove any menuItem from default menu items. Try this

```
    let configuration = buildConfiguration()
    var menuItems = MenuItem.defaultItems(with: configuration)

    menuItems.removeFirst() // Remove first menu item ('Transform')

    // Create a photo edit view controller
    let photoEditViewController = PhotoEditViewController(photo: photo, menuItems: menuItems, configuration: configuration)
```